# How do a linux application knows, which physical interface it can use?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, interface

I am new to writing a Linux application. From a developer's perspective, How do a linux application knows, which physical interface it can use to send data to remote application?
Do we need to register all the possible communication interfaces e.g. Bluetooth, Wifi, ethernet, etc. with the application so that it can search for the possible physical interface? If so, how do we do that?
What changes we need to make in a BSP?
Thanks.